how to create a ceph notification and receive object's changes?
I tried to get Ceph's message notification API, but found that it couldn't be turned on, so I ignored it, and then created a topic, created a rabbitmq message notification, but still couldn't receive the message notification.So I switched to the Kafka type of message notification, and still couldn't receive the message, and then I also consulted the official documentation of ceph, which talked about message notification, but there was no detailed operation, guiding me what to do

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
